# SSO Login & Creating a backend User with Protected Routes

Tags: react-native, mobile, oauth, expo, single-sign-on

I have a React Native app (Expo) with a Flask (Python) backend, and I want to implement Apple Sign In. Additionally, I need to create a corresponding user on my backend application, ensuring that all subsequent API requests are authenticated. (Eventually extend it to login with Google & Facebook)

I am struggling to determine how to create a user in my backend since the only thing I get back from Apple is their email/user ID/access & refresh token.

I can create a user with a fake password but when they login again, how can I determine its actually them?

I then need to "log them in" so they can hit protected routes from the App and I can update my backend API's. Do I make them a JWT token from the email/password I made? What happens if the JWT needs to be refreshed (the one I made?) Resend their Apple access token to my backend?

This is where I am confused how the flow should work. I can easily put together a bare bone, security issue central solution but I wanted to do it right the first time.

Things to consider:

**Apple Sign In on the App:**

- Integrate Apple Sign In functionality within your React Native app to obtain the user ID, access token, and refresh token.

**User Creation on Backend:**

- Upon receiving the tokens on the app, make a API call to your Flask backend to create a user. Store the user ID and tokens securely. (Do I make them a password?, do I check the JWT that Apple gave me for authenticity and extract the email?) What happens on Login from the app? What do I check?

**Authentication Mechanism:**

- Since Apple Sign In does not provide a password what now?

**JWT for API Authentication:**

- When the user logs in through Apple Sign In, do I generate a JWT on the backend side? Store it on the users local storage and Send this JWT along with each API request to my backend?

**Extracting User Information:**

Extract essential user information (such as email) from the JWT on the backend. This ensures that your backend has accurate user details for further processing.

In summary, the process involves creating a user on the backend with a random password, using JWTs for subsequent API authentication, and extracting necessary user information from the JWT on the backend. This approach allows you to seamlessly integrate Apple Sign In while maintaining secure authentication for your React Native app and Flask backend.

I got the Apple login working and get back Apple's JWT token with user_id and email.

Now I need to figure out how to create a user in my backend, how to handle logins, then do I create a JWT token from (backend) to host on the app?